# How to set up multiple occurences of same event with RNG?

Tags: rng

I am trying to find out what is the easiest way to handle this use case:

We host the same event in different cities. So event A will go to city X then city Y then city Z.

So all the information about the event is the same, just different dates and locations.

It is the same event so nobody will attend more than once. But many people will consider which city to attend the event (it may be the same distance if they go to city Y or city Z).

I assume each event should have its own RNG registration.

But what would be the easiest way to set up this thing with all the shared information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will need to create new event entities for each city, add a location field ([Address](https://www.drupal.org/project/address)?) and a date field, so your users can tell the difference. You will need to make the discovery layer before the event pages show a clear difference between your events: You could have a table view with the city and data in respective columns. Or a Google maps layer with pins for each city. Where each pin is a link to each event entity page.

If you are looking to enforce restrictions on people from attending both events, you can try [RNG Conflict](https://github.com/dpi/rng_conflict). However I don't think that is necessary in your case.